# What Should the Structure of virtualenv Environment Look Like

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv, development-environment

This is one of my first times really using `virtualenv` and when I first activated it I was (and am) a bit confused about where my actual project (like the code) should go. Currently (after making and activating the `virtualenv`) this is what my project looks like in `PyCharm`:

```
Project Name
|-project-name      <= I called my virtualenv project-name
  |-bin
    |-Lots of stuff here
  |-include
    |-Lots of stuff here
  |-lib
    |-Lots of stuff here
  |-.Python
  |-pip-selfcheck.json
```

**In this environment, where should I put my actual code?**

Comment: Nope, you should not place your project files into that directory. Take a look at `virtualenvwrapper` and how it solves that problem.

Comment: In a standard virtualenv, you put your code right there inside project-name.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Should I make a src file inside project-name to store the source files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you activate a virtual env using `virtualenv env`, env (where all of your dependencies will be installed), sits at the top of your root directory. Let's say you use [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) to create a project, you would then follow these steps:

1. Type `source env/bin/activate` to activate virtual environment
2. Type `pip install django` to install Django
3. Type `django-admin startproject my-example-proj`, which will install Django in your root directory

You should now how two directories: **env** and **my-example-proj**. You project never goes inside the **env** directory. That's where you install dependencies using **[pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)**.

Answer (score 6):

I don't recommend to put your project to virtualenv folder. I think you should do it in this way:

Do it in terminal if you're using Linux:

1. `mkdir project-name`.
2. `cd project-name`.
3. `virtualenvwrapper env`.
4. `source env/bin/activate`.

So you will have `project-name` folder where you will have all files according to your project + virtualenv folder called `env`.

If you don't have `virtualenvwrapper`, then just install it using `apt-get`:

`sudo apt-get install virtualenvwrapper`